# How to setup Bing Maps inside Power BI Custom Visuals?

Tags: powerbi, bing-maps

I am in the process of creating a custom visual for Power BI, and would like to include Bing Maps functionality within the plugin.  However, I am unable to initialize the Bing maps script within my custom visual's javascript class.

Here is the base code for the constructor of my class implementing IVisual:

```
    constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {

        console.log('Visual constructor', options);

        const initializer  = () => {

            if (typeof document !== "undefined") {

                //map setup
                const mapContainerDiv: HTMLElement = document.createElement("div");
                options.element.appendChild(mapContainerDiv);
                mapContainerDiv.id = options.element.id + "_mapDiv";

                const map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map("#" + mapContainerDiv.id,{
                    credentials: "xxx-my-key-xxx"
                });
            }

        };

        const mapScript: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
        mapScript.addEventListener("load", event => initializer());
        mapScript.async = true;
        mapScript.defer = true;
        mapScript.src = "https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap";

        options.element.appendChild(mapScript);

    }
```

The above code using the load event does not work, because I keep getting the following error from the mapcontrol javascript:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null."

Upon googling, it seems that using load events does not work with the newest version of Bing Maps, so another approach must be taken.

I then commented out the line that added the event listener to the mapScript tag, and changed the mapScript src line to the following, in order to use the recommended way by Bing Maps of triggering the callback:

```
mapScript.src = "https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=initializer";
```

The callback function is never called.

I then tried moving the initializer function outside of the constructor and declaring it as a public field on the class, but this did not work either.

What is the correct way to initialize Bing Maps in this situation?  All of the documentation I've seen shows that you have to create the callback for the Bing maps script URL in the global scope or in a script tag on the page, but within a Power BI custom visual, I can only manipulate my custom javascript class that implements IVisual. The default maps plugin from Microsoft within Power BI uses Bing Maps as its engine, so I know that it has to be possible somehow, I'm just not sure which approach to take.